# Exploiting structure in multilinear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I'm wondering if there are any standard techniques for exploiting structure in multilinear equations. An example of what I have in mind is solving

$A_{ab} X_{bc} A_{cd} (B_{ad} B_{bc} + B_{ac} B_{bd}) = RHS_{ad}$

for X. Here, A, B, and X are n-by-n matrices and there is summation over b,c. Of, course, one can view this as a large equation system

$M vec(X) = vec(RHS)$

where M has dimension n^2 by n^2. But I'd like to somehow exploit the structure of M to reduce the rank.

Comment: I can't see how this is multilinear, as the $ad$ indices are repeated like they should be summed.  It's not clear to me how they should be free on both sides.

Comment: I'm in agreement with Muphrid: Your indices don't make much sense. The first three terms seem to be just $(AXA)_{ad}$, but the next set of terms involving $B$ is not comprehensible.

Comment: @Muphrid, the example I gave arose starting from a "covariant" expression (where each dummy summation index occurs exactly twice, once in subscript position and once in superscript position), and then making an approximation that breaks covariance. I thought "multilinear" just meant something like a multi-dimensional array in most programming languages. So just disregard the word "multilinear". Alternatively, if you know any standard techniques for avoiding to solve a full n^2-by-n^2 equation system when the summation pattern is "covariant", that would be very interesting too.

Comment: For example, I've considered substituting A and B for their SVDs, but couldn't make much progress precisely because the coupling of summation indices don't follow normal matrix multiplication. I also know there are multi-index versions of SVDs (which do not hinge on covariant summation patterns), but couldn't figure out a use for them either here.